# django : Display modelformset, then edit, then save -

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-forms

I'm looking for a simple modelformset example - I have a model

```
class Category(BaseModel):

    categoryText = db.StringProperty()
    parentCat = db.IntegerProperty()
```

I am trying to create a formset to display all available Categories wihle they all could be edited and then submit the edits.

I am getting stuck where I get error that the fields are not editable.  According to the documentation I should set Category field editable=True - however there is no information about where I do that.  I've tried to set it in the model but I get errors.  and in the Form, I don't declare fields since it's a modelform !

when I try to display this formset I get : 
'StringProperty' object has no attribute 'editable'

I would appreciate any help - a basic example of the view and the model, form classes would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out -
I was using appengine helper as a patch to get django working - this patch does not support model formsets.  Must use GAE version of forms which is not as rich as Django.

For this reason I switched from appengine helper to non-rel - although I had some issues during install, this version of the patch is complete.
Django now works as described in documentation.

non-rel seems to be a better choice if you are new and trying to learn Django from the available docs.